# El uso de "estar" y "haber" en "Estaba mucha gente" / "Había mucha gente"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos, sintaxis

Soy profesora de español como lengua extranjera (ELE) y tengo dudas en una frase.

La siguiente frase es correcta, sin duda alguna:

> Había mucha gente.

Pero ¿es también posible decirlo así?

> Estaba mucha gente.

En el sentido de *allí se encontraba mucha gente*. ¿O NO es correcto el uso de *estar* en este caso?

La misma estructura en el presente (*hay mucha gente*, *está mucha gente*) me parece más rara que la del imperfecto, pero no sé por qué. ¿A lo mejor me equivoco y *estar* no es posible en absoluto?

Buscándolo en Internet aparecen algunos ejemplos con *estar*, pero eso no significa nada... A lo mejor aquí hay alguien que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Sin pensarlo muchísimo, me parece que decir «estaba mucha gente» casi se sobreentiende como «estaba presente mucha gente» (igual que me parece que ser se entendería con una función identificatoria). Incluso en el caso de no emplearlo apenas nadie, por lo menos gramáticamente no hay ningún error, es solo cuestión de uso.

Comment: Pues, "mucho" se entiende más como algo indeterminado como el artículo indeterminado (hay un/una...) y por eso cabe mejor el verbo haber, mientras que con estar se usa más bien el/la/los/las que mucho + gente, ¿correcto?

Comment: "Estaba mucha gente" como existencial es incorrecto, pero puedes encontrar el fragmento en otro contexto "estaba mucha gente preocupada con ese asunto" sí es correcto, también lo es "había mucha gente preocupada con ese asunto".

Comment: Mucha gente estaba en la fiesta. Y estoy de acuerdo con Davius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yo creo que es incorrecto.

Creo que el problema está en la sustitución inadecuada de "haber" por "estar" para denotar existencia.

Explican en fundéu en la entrada ["*había muchas personas*, no *habían muchas personas*"](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/habia-habian-muchas-personas-haber-uso-impersonal/)

> Como explica el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://www.rae.es/consultas/habia-muchas-personas-ha-habido-quejas-hubo-problemas), el uso impersonal del verbo *haber* tiene, entre otras funciones, la de **señalar la presencia o la existencia de lo referido por la palabra o palabras a las que acompaña**, como en «aquí hay mucha gente» o «ha habido cierto avance en las negociaciones».
>
> Estas palabras no constituyen el sujeto (con el que debe concordar el verbo), ya que se trata de un uso impersonal, sino el objeto directo (con el que no concuerda nunca el verbo), por lo que el verbo haber siempre debe aparecer en singular, es decir, no es adecuado escribir *habían muchas personas* ni *habrán muchas personas*, sino *había muchas personas* y *habrá muchas personas*.

Esta particularidad del verbo *haber* no se cumple para *estar*, ya que *haber* se usa para hablar de la **existencia** o no de personas, animales, objetos y lugares

- Hay un coche blanco en la calle
- Hay una farmacia en esa esquina

El verbo *estar* se usa para denotar estado ("estoy enfadado; el coche está roto") y una relación de *tiempo y espacio* (que está más relacionado con el uso antes mencionado de "haber", en el sentido de "denotar existencia", pero no llega a se exactamente lo mismo y por tanto un verbo no es sustituible por el otro en todos los casos).

Dice el DpD en su entrada para "haber" ([punto 4, uso como verbo impersonal](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=phjmVDAG4D6WPVG3Nr), en su explicación sobre si es )

> [...] la excepcionalidad que supone la existencia de un verbo impersonal transitivo, sumado al influjo de **otros verbos que comparten con haber su significado «existencial», como *estar***, existir, ocurrir, todos ellos verbos personales con sujeto, explica que muchos hablantes interpreten erróneamente el sustantivo que aparece pospuesto al verbo haber como su sujeto y, consecuentemente, pongan el verbo en tercera persona del plural cuando dicho sustantivo es plural

Que explica porqué "Hubieron muchos factores que se opusieron a la realización del proyecto" es erróneo y que lo correcto es "Hubo muchos factores que se opusieron a la realización del proyecto", pero quería recalcar de ese párrafo que haber y estar comparten ese "significado «existencial»". Y el propio DpD pone "existencial entrecomillado.

Aclarada esta particularidad de "haber" es su uso impersonal y las similitudes entre "haber" y "estar" para "denotar existencia", habría que recalcar que uno dice

- **Hay** un libro en la mesa

pero no

- Está un libro en la mesa

No es necesariamente incorrecto en todos los casos. La validez puede depender del contexto, pero creo que los contextos que lo harían válido serían aquellos en los que se usa "estar" para explicar una relación espacio-temporal, más que meramente *existencial*.

Es decir, como apunta guifa en su comentario, la validez de "estaba mucha gente" podría depender de un contexto en el que se sobreentendiese ""estaba mucha gente allí (en ese momento)" o, por poner otro ejemplo,

> Estaba un libro en la mesa

Es válido si quieres explicar que en un momento preciso, el libro se *encontraba* (que no deja de ser "existía") en la mesa ("Un libro estaba en la mesa" suena y se entiende mejor). Sin embargo, decir

> Estaba un libro (en la mesa)

Para decir que existía un libro (y que daba la casualidad de que su situación espacial era sobre una mesa) suena forzado, al intentar sustituir "haber" por "estar" para indicar "existencia".

Mi conclusión es por tanto que tal uso debe evitarse. Se entiende perfectamente, pero también se entiende usos incorrectos como "Hubieron muchos factores" o "habían muchas gentes". El verbo *estar* debería usarse para explicar una relación espacio-temporal y no una *existencial*.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por esta explicación detallada. Ahora lo comprendo perfectamente :)

Answer (score 0):

Se suele decir "había mucha gente" o "no había mucha gente".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24820)

Answer (score 0):

#### Coincido en que *"Estaba mucha gente"* es incorrecto

Además del uso que indica @Diego en su respuesta, **haber** se usa cuando el objeto animado es indeterminado. En el ejemplo,

- *había mucha gente*

La definición espacial y temporal está implicita, pero *gente* es genérico.

- *había mucha gente (en el mercado ayer por la tarde)*

Por otro lado, **estar** indica existencia de un objeto determinado en un lugar y un tiempo. Por ejemplo:

- *En la fiesta (de ayer) estaban Teresa, Estela, José ...*
- *Estoy (ahora) detrás de ti*
- *El famoso cantante estará dando autógrafos mañana despues del concierto*
- *Los cubiertos están en la mesa (no es genérico porque se refiere a unos cubiertos específicos)*
- *La gente está afuera (igualmente se refiere a unas personas específicas)*

#### Otros usos de *estar*

También **estar** denota estados (no se de que otra manera ponerlo).

- *Está amarillo del susto*
- *Los gatos están contentos*
- *¡Estoy muy enojado!*
- *Siempre estoy en movimiento*
- *Pedro no está casado*

Para estado civil también se puede usar **ser** (aunque no es parte de la pregunta lo pongo como complemento).

- *Pedro no es casado*